# Per-puzzle tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I've noticed a recurring theme in our tagging scheme: there are a lot of puzzle-specific tags, like [chess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess),[blackjack](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blackjack),[2048](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2048),[tic-tac-toe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tic-tac-toe),etc... I think we need to have a policy on these per-puzzle tags. My idea:

> We should have generalized tags, like [2048](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2048) in stead of [mega-2048](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mega-2048) and [3x3-2048](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3x3-2048)

Community input please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it, this is the same as using version numbers in tags. A puzzle should always have the general tag, e.g. [2048](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2048). If and only if the question is specific to one particular instance, we should tag it with that more specific tag. E.g. a question like "what do you get when combining two 4 tiles" would be tagged [2048](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2048), and a question like "what is the maximum possible tile achievable in 3x3 2048" would be [2048](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2048) [3x3-2048](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3x3-2048).

Answer (score 2):

This seems, quite bluntly, like an abuse of the tagging system.

First of all, tags are supposed to represent specific expertise. You can't possibly expect someone to be an expert on... all card games?

Secondly, knowing a question is about cards doesn't tell you anything. Blackjack and poker are completely different games, and the fact that they use the same materials makes them only tangentially related at most.

Also, tags are a way to filter for stuff you're interested in. What happens when you want to find all questions about blackjack, or if you don't care about poker and don't want to see it?

Comment: I was mainly talking about small tag differences, like different *similar* versions of the same puzzle/game.

Comment: @TheDoctor Blackjack and poker are not similar versions of the same game...

Comment: Edited... more similar puzzles. What i didn't was a seprate tag for every puzzle: [tag:6x6-additive-fibonacci-tile-game-a-little-like-2048]

Comment: @TheDoctor That seems like a given - we don't have those tags in the first place, and this applies to SE in general anyway.

Comment: This post is more appropriate as a comment as it does not attempt to answer the question.